# Настройка Nginx на подпапки(директорий) для разных сайтов на php

Tags: php, nginx

Cтруктура сайта такая.
example.com/blog(wordpress)
example.com/site1(php)
example.com/site2(html)
example.com/warehouse (craft cms)

Все это лежит в соответствующих папках в /var/www/
blog
site1
site2
warehouse

И все сайты работают/открываются исправно кроме warehouse,в nginx соотвествующий location прописываю для warehouse.

когда в браузере пытаюсь зайти по адресу example.com/warehouse то перекидывается на главную страницу с адресом example.com/?q=p:10

Если в браузере в ручную прописать папку example.com/warehouse/?q=p:10 то работает до следующего перехода по ссылкам и так каждый раз вставлять /warehouse приходится.

в логах cat /var/log/nginx/access.log

`[27/Sep/2018:22:38:20 +0500] "GET /warehouse/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
[27/Sep/2018:22:38:20 +0500] "GET /?q=p:10 HTTP/1.1" 403 152 "-" "Mozilla/5.0`

Пробовал разные конфигурации nginx но так или иначе все равно возвращаюсь к перекидыванию на главную страницу с неправильным адресом.

Можно ли заставить nginx подставлять папку в адресе чтобы ссылки полностью формировались вот так example.com/warehouse/?q=p:10

Если ставлю в чистую папку craft cms(php)в чистой папке /var/www все работает хорошо, а как перемещаю в подпапку /var/www/warehouse то начинается перекидывание на главную страницу.

сейчас конфиг nginx минимальный

```
server {
listen 80;
root /var/www;
index index.php index.html;
server_name _;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

location /blog {
    index   index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    }

location /site1 {
    index   index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /site1/index.php?$args;
    }

location /site2 {
    index   index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /site2/index.html?$args;
    }

# новый блок для warehouse
location /warehouse {
    index   index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /warehouse/index.php?$args;
    }

# php блок
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

так же сделал

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

sudo chmod 0755 -R /var/www

Возможно дело craft cms в файлах настроек вроде init.php
но разбираться в фреймворке долго, хотя знающие php, может подскажут.

**Знаю можно разнести на поддомены но мне нужно именно из подпапки)**

Я был бы очень благодарен если бы подсказали в чем дело.

Comment: Попробуйте вот так try_files $uri $uri/ /warehouse/index.php?p=$uri&$args; А то мне кажется что вы конфиг от WP для крафта юзаете. Если поможет оформлю в ответ

Comment: @Taarim спасибо за отклик, добавил вместо старого в location /warehouse, перезагрузил, example.com/warehouse ничего, в логах
`[28/Sep/2018:17:52:04 +0200] "GET /warehouse HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
[28/Sep/2018:17:52:04 +0200] "GET /warehouse/ HTTP/1.1" 404 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0`
если ввожу example.com/warehouse/index.php то опять перекидывает на example.com/?q=p:3
в логах вот что
cat /var/log/nginx/error.log
`2018/09/28 17:57:00 [error] 2790#2790: *5 directory index of "/var/www/" is forbidden, client: 192.168.77.53, server: _, request: "GET /?q=p:1 HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"`

Comment: так вы сами первым localtion поставили '/' он и матчится всегда

Comment: @Naumov если его убираю то ничего не изменяется, все так же(